# Load body content from off page -> left to right on page load

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page effect similar to paper coming out of a copier machine.  I want the body content when done loading to appear from left to right.  I have seen many examples on how to do this with induivale elements like images but not the whole page.  Here is a code example I pieced together.  I can't seem to get the left to right effect I am looking for and this does not work with IE.  I just started coding web pages so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>

    body { padding-left: 5000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all .5s ease; }

    .loaded { padding-left: 5px; }

  </style>

  <script>function loaded (el) { el.classList.add('loaded') }</script>

</head>
<body onload="loaded(document.body)">
<br><br><br><br><br>

<table class="tftable" border="0" width="400">
  <tr><th></th></tr>
  <tr><td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use jQuery.animate instead of css animations

Answer (score 0):

play with that code it helps you put the animation on the body

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-direction